# Getting: dial tcp: lookup db on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host,

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have tried whatever solutions were provided but nothing works

I don't have any host port like this 127.0.0.11:53: to connect to the database, I am using docker-compose for the database.

I am not sure why I am getting this error

SQL database: "database/sql"

driver: "github.com/lib/pq"

docker-compose file

```
services:
  db:
    hostname: db
    image: postgres:10.7
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 54321:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: dbuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    volumes:
      - db-data1:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - my_network
```

Comment: Make your question clear & informative so people can help you better. Edit your question and tell which solutions you've tried. for now, I just think your docker is not running.

Comment: What is the problem? What does the docker-compose file you shared have to do with port 53?

Comment: From where are you attempting to connect to the database? You only show a single container in your `docker-compose.yaml` file; if you start a container manually with `docker run` it won't be able to lookup the `db` hostname unless you explicitly connect it to the same Docker network as the postgres container (using the `--network <network_name>` option).

Comment: @Bergi `127.0.0.11` is the address of the Docker-managed DNS server, and the error reported is because of a failed lookup for the hostname `db` from within some container.

Comment: @larsks "within some container" - yeah, that's exactly the details we are missing